# Throttling an AMQP Consumer Using RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using AMQP in a reliability pattern and my use-case is to put messages in a queue, then consume them and insert the information into a web service. My web service is slow, and my queue can have many, many messages and I would like to ensure that the consumer doesn't kill my database.

Is there a build-in way to perform throttling in RabbitMQ, either time-based(only X messages per minute/second/hour) or some other mechanism?

Comment: Just a comment related to channel.flow: this has been deprecated from the version 3.3.0 http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/02/breaking-things-with-rabbitmq-3-3/

Answer (score 1):

There is [per-connection](http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html#per-connection) flow control, so if you have too much messages on server, publishers will be awaiting. RabbitMQ is very reliable system, i can say that you can no worry about it.

If you are talking about how to limit consumption, probably you have to take care about it by yourself. You may also look on <s>[channel.flow](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#channel.flow)</s> (deprecated as of [RabbitMQ 3.3.0](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/02/breaking-things-with-rabbitmq-3-3/)) and [basic.qos](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.qos) methods or you can even temporary disconnect consumer(s) and reconnect them back when your services will be capable to take the load.

**UPD**
I can suggest that you consume messages with [basic.consume](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.consume) and feed it to your web service. Based on how long does you web service process payload you may guess it's load and do some kind of `sleep(N)`. While your consumer be sleeping it will not consume anything so no web service will be fed.

Comment: I'm not really worried about the Broker backing up, I'm more worried about overloading my web service with too many connections if I have my AMQP connector pulling all the messages it can at one time.

Comment: which language do you use for app writing?

Comment: Java. I was hoping not to have to write my own logic for this and that RabbitMQ/AMQP might have something built-in.

Comment: There are two main methods to get messages from broker: basic.get to acquire one message, if any, and basic.consume to consume messages continuously as far as they are available on queue. Based on this info and my update above you can just basic.get message according to your web service availability. Note, that basic.get may return no message if there are no message for this queue. There should be no platform-specific issue with such approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if "Per-Connection Flow Control" is related with the [channel.flow()](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#channel.flow).

Basically you can call `channel.flow(false);` to inform the broker to stop sending messages.
Calling `channel.flow(true);` makes the flow active again. Here's the [javadoc](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.2.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.2.4/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#flow%28boolean%29).